# remove active from bootstrap select2 on search

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap selectpicker in one of my project - https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

here is my code

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple data-actions-box="true">
  <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>
```

javascript:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('show');
```

I have one issue while i search in the dropdown the top first search items are getting highlighted (blue color) without selecting. I want that active class only on click not in search criteria. Is there any way of it?
here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/poy0o5ss/2/

Answer (score 0):

Since your's is a special case, which is dynamically remove the `.active` while searching. You need to target the `.on('input')` event listener **on the search input** and remove the `active` class from the dropdown. Like so

```
$(function() {
   //This event is fired when the dropdown has been made visible to the user
   $('.selectpicker').on('shown.bs.select', function (e) {
     $('ul.dropdown-menu li:first').removeClass('active');
   });

   $('.form-control').on('input',function(e){
     $('ul.dropdown-menu li:first').removeClass('active');
   });
});
```

This works well even when you fire backspace key on the search query.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/poy0o5ss/5/)

Comment: No when i remove the "multiple" it agains showning active the first li
https://jsfiddle.net/poy0o5ss/4/

Comment: So you just need to remove the class from `shown.bs.select` event type too. thats it. Updated the answer.

Comment: where did you update ?? Can you share with me the jsfiddle please?

Comment: You did a good try but the first li never gets selected.. So it must be dynamic as well  :(

Comment: Yup sadly that's the limitation of this library :( You could even try using `one()`[jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_one.asp) method, But I'm sure even this is not you would want.